# I want to generate boiler plate code in my repository pattern project

Tags: .net-core, boilerplate

As title suggests, I am creating open source project that is in .net core 2.0. here is the architecture of it.

[image]

Now, it's working fine with everything including code first, seeders, swagger UI, TDD etc.
But there are many places where **I have to add/modify classes when I want to add new Table in Database** (see SimpleCRUD.Model > Entities)

So, I think I can reduce that boilerplate code, but I am not sure what is best way to do it.

> What I did so far?

I tried to create a windows app, which will check and generate code for new added entity.

> What I am trying to achieve?

Is there anyway I can add some kind of code in my current project and that will check after each build? is it feasible? any other suggestion to make it working perfectly?

> Reference

I have checked this working in few other frameworks like serenity, asp.net boilerplate etc.

Comment: Take a look at T4 templates.

Comment: Can you use [AutomaticMigrationsEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.automaticmigrationsenabled(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

T4 temples can help cut down the boiler plate...

https://dotnetthoughts.net/generate-your-database-entities-using-t4-templates/

Answer (score 1):

You've asked for my help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037210/how-can-we-get-the-t4-template-to-generate-code-based-on-a-cs-file-that-the-use/32040645?noredirect=1#comment89893747_32040645)

I agree with other posters that you might want to look into T4. It sounds like you also want to create an [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks).

I outlined the steps to do this for a different question in post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182441/calling-a-class-in-the-same-project-from-t4-template/22184169#22184169)

You can find my code generators under this folder, [CodeGen.SessionProxies](https://github.com/psgivens/AppSessionFramework/tree/master/CodeGen.SessionProxies)

The t4 example can be found here: [AppSessionPartials.tt](https://github.com/psgivens/AppSessionFramework/blob/master/CodeGen.SessionProxies/tools/AppSessionPartials.tt)

The MSBuild task can be found here: [GenerateSessionProxies.cs](https://github.com/psgivens/AppSessionFramework/blob/master/CodeGen.SessionProxies/GenerateSessionProxies.cs)

I had it generating a nuget file through the [CodeGen.SessionProxies.nuspec](https://github.com/psgivens/AppSessionFramework/blob/master/CodeGen.SessionProxies/CodeGen.SessionProxies.nuspec). You won't find it on nuget.com; I had a local nuget repository. It would be helpful to you to look at the corresponding [install.ps1](https://github.com/psgivens/AppSessionFramework/blob/master/CodeGen.SessionProxies/tools/install.ps1) to understand how to set the generator up as a msbuild task.

Disclaimer: All of the GitHub links are subject to break if I ever decide to clean up that repo.

Cheers